# How to create UDF in Azure synapse with column as input parameter and return a table?

Tags: select, split, user-defined-functions, azure-synapse

I have a select query which need to converted to UDF in Azure Synapse.

```
Declare @periodstring = '(''2007-08-09'', ''2009-08-25'')'
select FIRST_VALUE(case when ordinal=1 then cast(replace(replace(value, '(''', ''), '''', '') as DATETIME2) end) over (partition by @periodstring order by @periodstring) as startdate,
     LAST_VALUE(case when ordinal=2 then cast(replace(replace(value, ''')', ''), '''', '') as DATETIME2) end) over (partition by @periodstring order by @periodstring) as enddate
     FROM STRING_SPLIT(@periodstring, ',', 1)
```

Want to create a UDF which takes table column as input parameter and return a table or datettime columns as output.

How to go ahead with this or is there any other way to handle this??

Comment: Azure Synapse Analytics, dedicated SQL pools support inline table-valued functions not multi-statement functions.  Read about inline table-valued functions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-sql-data-warehouse?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7) and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Synapse Analytics, dedicated SQL pools support scalar functions, inline table-valued functions not multi-statement functions. Read about both scalar and inline table-valued functions with Synapse [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-sql-data-warehouse?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7) and give it a try.